# Changing the background color and shape of the zoom buttons, AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

[image][image]I have a sin function in my graph, and the user is able to select points on it. However, when the only PointStyle in the renderer is POINT, the background of the zoom color is white/transparent (not sure since my background is white). However, when I add PointStyle.CIRCLE (for when the user selects a point on the function) the background of the zoom buttons change to gray. When I remove the point, it changes back to white/transparent.

Is there a way to force the background color of the zoom buttons?

Also, is there a way to change the container shape of the zoom buttons. From round corners to sharp corners. Perhaps by override?

Comment: Can you please post some screenshots? I don't understand exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I updated with the latest library, now I get what you see in the screenshot. This is not related with my original question, but is there any way to make this all white? Once this is answers, I can demonstrate my original question.

Comment: renderer.setMargisnColor();

Comment: It seems like the issue that I described before doesn't happen anymore with the nightly builds. However, my question could easily be simplified by saying: "is it possible to change the background of the zoom buttons? From gray to something else.". Sorry for the mess I made of this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the zoom buttons look and feel. However, you can create your custom zoom buttons and hide the default ones.